# Unable to get IMEI in dubbed android phone?

Tags: android

I am trying the code below to get the IMEI number from android mobile.

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

// Use permission into your Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Unfortunately for dubbed or FCC certified phones are not providing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an alternative to get IMEI number using **ANDROID_ID**

```
String identifier = null;
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (tm != null)
      identifier = tm.getDeviceId();
if (identifier == null || identifier .length() == 0)
      identifier = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```